# How to Calculate measurement %sale Proportion in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm newbie in PowerBI user.I create simple sale report and measurement. Like This :
[image]

My problem.In PowerBI show % calculate only Net sale and total rows but I need all % sale result like this :

[image]
[image]

Please suggest me how to solve this problem.This's my Code.

```
% to Sales = round(DIVIDE(
sum(DAILY_PNL_FF_TH_V2[VALUE]),
CALCULATE(sum(DAILY_PNL_FF_TH_V2[VALUE]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(ERP_ACCOUNT[group_1]),ERP_ACCOUNT[group_1]="Net Sales")
))*100,2) &"%"
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive and specific about your problem. You don't need to share your actual datasets, just fake data. It appears 2 tables on your measure also. What those tables represent?

Comment: Are you trying to divide each `group_1` amount by the total of net sales?

Comment: Yes I try to divide each group1 by total Net sales.But It show only total and Net sale it not show another in group1.T T

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the Percent of each group relative to `Net Sales`, then you can try something like below:

```
% to Sales =
VAR netSalesAmount =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( DAILY_PNL_FF_TH_V2[VALUE] ),
        ERP_ACCOUNT[group_1] = "Net Sales"
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( SUM ( DAILY_PNL_FF_TH_V2[VALUE] ), netSalesAmount )
```

Also, it is better to address formatting in the screen below so that the number is treated as a number rather than text.  This is both for sorting and exporting the data.  Also, it keeps the calculation simpler:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code.It's show only Net sales and total rows.